# How to remove automatically subscribed calendar for public holidays on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, ical

As you can see in the screenshot below, somehow my iPhone subscribed to a calendar which is called "Deutsche Feiertage" (German public holidays).

How can I find out where this is coming from and how can I remove it (not just hide or disable notification)?

[image]

I am not hundert percent sure, but I think it is there since I upgraded my Mac to macOS 10.12. It was also there in the calendar app. There it was really easy to delete it. But I cannot find I way to get rid of it on my iPhone (using iPhone 6 Plus with iOS 10.2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't delete the iOS holidays calendar, only hide it. It is a subscribed calendar but it's part of iOS.

Comment: What a wonderful piece of human-centred design by Apple.

Comment: That evokes the response "Apple, you keep using that word, but I do not think it means what you think it means."

If it is forced upon you then you are not a 'subscriber' - I don't 'subscribe to the federal tax system' for example, it is imposed.  The US Holidays are forcibly imposed.  So putting the text "subscribed" under it in the calendar list is a comical lie.

Answer (score 0):

Open your calendar, at the bottom center of your screen select "Calendars":

[image]

Go down to "Holidays in the US" and deselect the check mark on the left side of your screen:

[image]

You're done!

[image]

Comment: Yes this is how to hide a calendar. I want to delete it.

Comment: Not possible - the built in US Holidays cannot be removed - the "subscribed" text is a lie - the calendar is imposed on you and all you can do is choose to ignore it.  It should be called (Apple Curated US Holidays and Crap) with the subtitle that replaces "Subscribed" being "Built in"

Answer (score 0):

Change your iOS region to Italy:

- Settings
- General
- Language & Region
- Region

(This is for iOS 14)

I don’t know why, but it looks like Italy does not enforce a subscribed Italian holiday calendar. I’m sure more countries are like that, so you could try to find another country that doesn’t add their calendar.

Answer (score -1):

Go to calendars, open calendar at bottom middle of the screen, scroll down to other, there should be a “birthday” item ticked.
Untick said item this will then delete all national birthday items.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  The answer you provided was already included in another answer.  What additional info can you provide?