# iOS holiday calendar becomes "Untitled Calendar"

Tags: ios, calendar

I just notice the iOS holiday calendar on my iPhone (running iOS 11.4) becomes "Untitled Calendar".

[image: Untitled Calendar]

According to [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/267700/150862), the holiday calendar is a part of iOS so there is no way to remove this calendar and then re-add it. It appears that this problem has existed since iOS 10.3.1 (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7915337).

Do anybody encounter this problem? Any suggestion on a solution or workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Yes change location to US Virgin Islands then go to http://icalshare.com/ and subscribe to any calendar that you like.

I've been on support line with Apple for 2 hours and had to come up with this solution on my own. They are no help and very condescending.